# HTML CSS JS onload change image size bad scale

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need scale image smooth, variable is image height, width is auto scaling by height size with css `width: auto`

**css and HTML**:

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%; /* if i change size here example: 300px get good scale */
  margin-top: 15px;
}

footer img[usemap] {
  border: none;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <img src='https://burritojustice.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/img_3769.jpg' usemap="#Map" name="#Map" id="map">
</footer>
```

**javascript:**

```
$('footer').css('height', '300px'); //if i change size here get bad scale
/* at the result i need write with javascript how much height it's my image and get nice scale */
```

If i change css line: `height: 100%` to `height: 300px` it's works good width change together height by scale, but if i try to change value with javascript like this: `$('footer').css('height', '300px');` it's works bad, also get 300px height but width remains the same not scaling.

https://jsfiddle.net/bddgo26o/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you wand to resize the height of the footer, and get the image resizing with the same proportions ?

If this is what you need, I have a solution in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcfuub3k/)

Basically, You are resizing the footer, so the image is resizing it height. But the original image size never change, so does the width.

I added this code to change the image height (to make it the same as the footer) :

```
$('footer img[usemap]').height($("footer").height());
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the v3 of the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bddgo26o/3/

Is that what you need?

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20%; /* if i change size here example: 300px get good scale */
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

footer img[usemap] {
    border: none;
   max-height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
}


$('footer').css('height', '50%'); //now changing gets ok
```

Comment: You need doing it "by javascript"? I´m not sure if I really understood you

Comment: I need do it with javascript

Comment: just added the footer css to see it was also working. (not assigning image height to footer height, as I think it´s better to not doing it). Just CSS and no more.

Comment: Ow thanks i give you rep when i reach 15 reputation, because now i don't have permission to give :)